I was doing 2 CTF exercises from college and I reached a point where I can't progress anymore, if anyone can help me, I would be very grateful
"In this challenge, participants must investigate a fictional website in search of hidden information that will lead to the discovery of a flag. The main skill to be tested is the ability to explore websites and find hidden data using different tools and analysis techniques."
Target site: http://192.241.168.233/
"Students are participating in a Capture The Flag (CTF) competition where they must explore the server to identify running services, the objective, and find the service and obtain the hidden flag."
Target site: http://192.241.168.233/
I tried commands like nmap but didn't get any significant results. The only information I could gather was about some directories, but they returned a 403 error.

Better post your question in security.stackexchange.com (post more details of the site, what you have done using nmap, etc.)
